# AutoComplete Textbox to detect if text is typed from user or appended from AutoComplete collection?

Tags: vb.net, autocomplete, textbox

I have created an autocomplete textbox with mode of  SuggestAndAppend text. I would like to detect if the text in the textbox is newly typed by user, or it is just appended from the Source Collection?

it can be checked when the textbox loose focus, but is there another way to detect immediately as the focus still in the textbox?

any idea?

Comment: I would think that a combination of the `KeyPress` and `TextChanged` events would give you the information you needed. You could store the current `Text` value in a field on `TextChanged`, store any new keyboard input in another field on `KeyPress` and then, on the next `TextChanged`, compare the current `Text` to see if it is the result of the previous `Text` and the keyboard input or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for the time being, I could write a code to implement the task. right now, this code can detect if the newly typed text is not a part of any items in the collection. but what if the user typed a newly text which can be considered as a part of an entry in the collection? i.e what if the collection contains entries like : BBC, CNN, FOX New and user wants to type only CN ( Cartoon Network)..in this case "CN" will be a part of CNN and then the code will not detect it as a new entry.

```
Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
    Dim isNew As Boolean = True

    For i As Integer = 0 To TextBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource.Count - 1
        If UCase(Trim(TextBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource(i))) Like UCase(Trim(TextBox1.Text)) & "*" Then
            isNew = False
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    If isNew = True Then
        MsgBox("Custome")
    Else

    End If
End Sub
```

the below code can chick if the text in textbox is new to collection or no, for the time being, it catch it in Leave Event. it should be improved to catch [Enter] key as well

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Leave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.Leave
    Dim isNew As Boolean = True

    For i As Integer = 0 To TextBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource.Count - 1
        If TextBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource.Contains(UCase(Trim(TextBox1.Text))) Then
            isNew = False
        End If
    Next

    If isNew = True Then
        MsgBox("Custome")
    Else

    End If

End Sub
```